# BIRT programatically get data from CSV data source

Tags: java, csv, report, birt

I have code which uses BIRT 2.6.1 runtime to get data from JDBC data source which works fine. but I want to change it to use a CSV file instead. what's the code to achieve this?

I have the following:

```
    OdaDataSourceHandle dsHandle = designFactory.newOdaDataSource(
            this.dataSourceName, "org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc" );
```

so what I am looking for is the 2nd parameter "extension id" for the csv type. flat file is supported in GUI.. so it should be exposed via api. although the only data packages I see are jdbc and xml.

Answer (score 0):

got it. "org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile" is the extensionId. which I obtained by running birt in the design mode and checking the XML.